# Programmatically determine maximum filename length

Tags: php, linux, path, filenames, name-length

How can I determine the maximum filename length on a linux box?

Preferred in PHP programming language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`pathconf` or `fpathconf`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pathconf.html), which are not exposed (yet) in PHP.  (When they are, they'll probably be `posix_pathconf`.)

You may also shell out to [`getconf`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/getconf.html), a command-line utility interface to the same functionality.  Try this on your system:

`$ getconf NAME_MAX /tmp`

`$ getconf PATH_MAX /tmp`

Answer (score 5):

there's no need to programatically determine it. it's 255 bytes.

edit: you can have longer filenames on a very few file systems (reiser, i believe), but if you stick to 255 your app will be usable on any linux installation.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum file length for *most* linux file systems is 255. You're probably best off using that as a generic constant and modifying to fit your known file system in linux. Here's a nice [comparison of the file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems) that might be used. Max file length is listed there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the constant PHP_MAXPATHLEN

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use realpath(). I'm not sure best approach, but for example:

**$maxlen=264-strlen(realpath('index.php')));**

264 is 255(max path lim) + 9 ('index.php' len). So substracting current path length from limit gives you max current path length.

Comment: You are confusing path max len (usually 4096) with file name max len (usually 255).